# How does multi-type damage work?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage-types

The attack "Storm Hammer" says hit:1d8+_(wisdom modifier)lighting and thunder damage... how do I tell how much damage to inflict?

Comment: Each time you use this attack, you will roll one 8-sided die and add your wisdom modifier (not score), then do this amount of damage.

Comment: @Dakeyras I took a guess and assumed the question was mostly related to the fact that it was "lightning and thunder"-typed damage.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.StackExchange.com.  Please take a look at the [About] page when you get a chance (you can get a badge for it).

Answer (score 6):

The *amount* of damage is equal to rolling an 8-sided die, and adding your Wisdom modifier to it. So **for example** if you have 16 Wisdom, your modifier is +3, and if you roll a 4 on the 8-sided die, you get 4+3 = 7 damage.

The *type* of the damage is both Thunder and Lightning. That is to say, for the above example, you do **not** deal 4 Lightning and 3 Thunder damage or something, it deals 7 (Lightning and Thunder) damage.

Multi-typed damage basically counts as whatever is best for you: the target uses the lowest resistance it has to any of the listed types.

So in the case of Storm Hammer, immunity to Lightning damage does no good: the creature would then have to use its Thunder resistance (if any). To be completely immune, the creature would need immunity to *both*. If the creature is vulnerable to either type, it takes that extra damage. If it is vulnerable to both, then it takes the extra damage from *each*.

Comment: So does lightning deal 4 damage and thunder deal 3?

Comment: No, you deal 7 damage, which is classed as both Lightning and Thunder at the same time. A creature immune to Thunder damage would still take 7 damage, because the damage is also classed as Lightning.

Comment: Why exactly does it deal 7? Will anything's classed as lightning and thunder always deal 7 damage?

Comment: @john the "7" is an example, obtained by positing that the 1d8 roll gave a 4, and the character had a +3 as Wisdom modifier. You seem a bit confused about basic mechanics. Have you ever played DnD or any other tabletop RPG?

Comment: I've played the Red Box,did a lot of research and read the rules book. I'm looking to really get into it but have to no one to really ask a lot of questions. What exactly is the point of the "thunder and lightning damage" does it effect anything?

Comment: @John The point of thunder-and-lightning is that it benefits from anything that improves thunder, anything that improves lightning, and affects things that are immune to one but not the other. It's quite beneficial.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much for the answers. It's difficult learning this game when it's just you and books hah.

Comment: @John that is true of any RPG lol, a big thing with 4e is keywords which damage type is an example of. Feats, class features, powers and items all interact with one another based off of keywords.